# Android Studio 3.1.3: Custom View: Layout can't find View Activity

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

There is a bug in Android Studio 3.1.3 when I create a Custom View:

**Steps:**

I created a clean project.

Since the layout editor breaks. I change com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3 to com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1 in the build.gradle. That fix the issue. Everything works.

Next, I created a package folder. Right-click on it. Select New -> UI Component -> Custom View.

In the layout editor, I get 1 error:

[image]

(I know, the package name sucks. I am just testing creating a custom view)

Which is weird because the class exists:

[image]

Humoring the message, I click on "Create Class"

[image]

When I press OK, I get:

[image]

So, what its needed to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to fix it is to delete the View file, and then use the "Create Class" Link.